# Is AI and Big Data science recommending a shift in the scientific method from inductive to deductive reasoning?

Tags: philosophy

Is this true?  Are we planning to switching such reasoning methods regarding AI tech in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You could argue that AI and big data are trying to switch the AI method from deductive to inductive reasoning in the sense that original AI was deductive (if...then conditionals) but deep learning implies inductive reasoning (feed the network a million images of white swans and the network will "conclude" all swans are white - the classic example of (erroneous) inductive reasoning.)